# How to share directory between sibling (DooD) docker containers?

Tags: docker, devops

I'm trying to containerized a controller that is capable of spawning DooD sibling containers:

```sh
[root@host]$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock controller ...
```

The controller receives uploaded files, does some local processing, creates worker container of the right type, and dispatches the request to workers, waiting for generated output files to return to the client:

```
[root@controller]$ docker run -v /tmp/files:/home/worker/workspace worker ...
```

Unfortunately the code above does not work, because the worker's `/home/worker/workspace` directory is actually mapped to `/tmp/files` of the **HOST** rather than the controller.

The controller container itself persists no data, thus has no explicit volume mapping from the host.

Any way to share the directory `/tmp/files` from the controller container to the sibling worker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a named volume.

Simply use

```
[root@host]$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v my_named_volume:/tmp/files controller ...
```

and

```
[root@controller]$ docker run -v my_named_volume:/home/worker/workspace worker ...
```

Guess that should do the trick.

Comment: Just a quick followup, is it possible to map not the entire volume, but a dynamically generated directory within the volume by the controller to the workspace folder in the worker?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not supported. There is an ongoing discussion about it. But it it is not implemented.
[Open Issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32582)

Answer (score 0):

why not make services with same volume mount using docker compose

it can something like

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    controller:
        container_name: controller
        build:
            context: ./demo
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - "./demo:/home/controller/workspace"
        ports:
            - 8080:8080

    worker:
        container_name: worker
        build:
            context: ./demo
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - "./demo:/home/worker/workspace"
        ports:
            - 8081:8080
```

Comment: There are potentially many different types of worker images that can be added dynamically. I'm not sure if docker compose is a good fit for that. Any recommendations?